# Why output of given JavaScript code is string?

Tags: javascript

```js
var z = 1,
  y = z = typeof y;
console.log(z); // >> 'string'
```

Why the value of z would be string.

Comment: Actually it's undefined.

Comment: What would you expect it to be and why?

Comment: Should return `undefined`, how it returns string to you?

Comment: @Aaron: doesn't reproduce for me (unless you define `y` as a string first)

Comment: It outputs `undefined` if you run it once, `string` if you run it more than once.

Answer (score 0):

It is hoisting the variable's declaration and the value is `'undefined'`.

```js
var z, y;

z = 1,
y = z = typeof y;

console.log(z, typeof z);
console.log(y, typeof y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's normal that you get `string`, because you are storing in `z` the result of the `typeof y` expression, which will give you a string containing the type of your object.

Consider the following:

```
var a = typeof undefined;
console.log(a); // returns "undefined" which is string.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only run this code, the value of `z` is `"undefined"`. If you run it more than once, the value of `z` will be `"string"`.

Breakdown:

```
var z = 1, y = z = typeof y;
console.log(z); // >> 'string'
```

This executes in the following order:

1. Assign 1 to `z`. The value of `z` is `1`.
2. Evaluate `typeof y`. This evaluates to `"undefined"` because the value of `y` is `undefined`.
3. Evaluate `z = "undefined"`. The value of `z` is `"undefined"`.
4. Evaluate `y = "undefined"`. The value of `y` is `"undefined"`.
5. Log the value of `z`. This logs `undefined`.

Running it a second time, you get:

1. Assign 1 to `z`. The value of `z` is `1`.
2. Evaluate `typeof y`. This evaluates to `"string"` because the value of `y` is `"undefined"`.
3. Evaluate `z = "string"`. The value of `z` is `"string"`.
4. Evaluate `y = "string"`. The value of `y` is `"string"`.
5. Log the value of `z`. This logs `string`.

Answer (score 0):

It returns `undefined` string because you assign result of `typeof y` to `z` variable and `y` is not defined at that moment. Also please remember that `typeof` operator always returns a string indicating the type.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening behind the scenes with your code is the following:

1. The interpreter sees the keyword "var" and creates some memory for the reference name "z" and "y" with the default value of undefined for both. In your case you are not explicitly using the keyword "var" for "y" because you are using a shorthand method which translates to:

```js
var z = undefined;
var y = undefined;
```

2. In step two the assigning of values happen. Notice that you assign to "y" the value from "z" which is the typeof "y" in this case is undefined:

```js
z = 1;
console.log(z) // z is now 1
z = typeof y
console.log(z) // undefined
console.log(y) // undefined
y = z
console.log(z) // undefined
console.log(y) //undefined
```

Do not get tricked by the result undefined and treat it as string.

```
console.log(typeof undefined) // "undefined"
console.log(typeof "undefined") // string
```

Undefiend is a type unless you explicitly assign to "undefined" in this case the quotes make it a string

In your case to throw "string" you have to console.log(typeof z) and will throw string because you have assigned z to "undefined" not undefined